# How to Move or Copy Specific Line To Specific Line

Tags: move, lines

I want to move or copy a line to another line. My txt is like that :

**/////1\\\\\**
**XXX-TEST**

**Abcdefghhghhfhf**

I want to copy or move line which starting with **XXX** to between **/////** and **\\\\\**

So I want to do this :

**/////XXX-TEST\\\\\**
**XXX-TEST**

**Abcdefghhghhfhf**

or

**/////1-XXX-TEST\\\\\**
**XXX-TEST**

**Abcdefghhghhfhf**

or

**/////XXX-TEST\\\\\**

**Abcdefghhghhfhf**

Thanks you for your replies.

Comment: please show the code you have written to attempt to solve this problem

Comment: It is not code. I want to do this process via Notepad++